# How do I save changes to a docker container and image

Tags: docker

I ran a container and it was missing command alias like `ll`. So I Typed `alias ll="ls -lta"` in the terminal while I was inside the container. After that, I ran `docker commit` to commit changes to the container and image. I got a new image (outside container), deleted the old image and ran a new container from the image I committed to. But was not able to use `ll` alias. What am I missing here?

Comment: Typically a Docker container packages a single application and its immediate dependencies; you don't usually do a whole lot of work in interactive shells in containers, since anything you edit there will be lost as soon as you delete the container.

Answer (score 2):

Container state is only persisted through files.

`alias ll="ls -lts"` made no file changes and thus no state change was persisted by the `docker commit...`.

You may achieve the result you intend by editing one of the files that the shell uses to define its state when opened, e.g. e.g. `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`. You'll need to determine which to use for your environment|OS.